# .htaccess does not work on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My server is connecting several VirtualHost. (like a.com, b.com ...)

a.com is connected to /var/www/a
b.com is connected to /var/www/b

I want to use a.com as dynamic subdomain, and I decided to use .htaccess on /var/www/a

There are no syntax error in .htaccess

mod_rewrite is also installed and load_module is called

"AllowOverride all" is also set in httpd.conf

permission checking.. of course

Basically, all alternatives that can be searched by Google are dealt with.
But .htaccess does not work.
Do you have any other unknown experience with this?

Comment: You may have miss spelled the name `.htaccess` (careful: unicode, blanks, ...!) or the name of such _`.htaccess` style files_ have been altered in the http servers configuration.

Comment: Thank you! There are terrible space character. I was found it on VI.